# Comparing two lists [R]

Tags: r, match

I have two rather long lists (both are 232000 rows).  When trying to run analyses using both, R is giving me an error that some elements in one lists are not in the other (for a particular code to run, both lists need to be exactly the same).  I have done the following to try and decipher this:

```
#In Both
both <- varss %in% varsg
length(both)

#What is in Both
int <- intersect(varss,varsg)
length(int)

#What is different in varss
difs <- setdiff(varss,varsg)
length(difs)

#What is different in varsg
difg <- setdiff(varsg,varss)
length(difg)
```

I think I have the code right, but my problem is that the results from the code above are not yielding what I need.  For instance, for `both <- varss %in% varsg` I only get a single `FALSE`.  Do both my lists need to be in a specific class in order for this to work?  I've tried `data.frame`, `list` and `character`.  Not sure whether anything major like a `function` needs to be applied.

Just to give a little bit more information about my lists, both are a list of SNP names (genetic data)

Edit:

I have loaded these two files as `readRDS()` and not sure whether this might be causing some problems.  When trying to just use `varss[1:10,]` i get the following info:

```
 [1] rs41531144 rs41323649 exm2263307 rs41528348 exm2216184 rs3901846 
 [7] exm2216185 exm2216186 exm2216191 exm2216198
232334 Levels: exm1000006 exm1000025 exm1000032 exm1000038 ... rs9990343
```

I have little experience with `RData` files, so not sure whether this is a problem or not...

Same happens with using `varsg[1:10,]` :

```
 [1] exm2268640 exm41      exm1916089 exm44      exm46      exm47     
 [7] exm51      exm53      exm55      exm56     
232334 Levels: exm1000006 exm1000025 exm1000032 exm1000038 ... rs999943
```

Comment: I know your data is huge, but can you provide a simplified example of what `varss` and `varsg` are? Preferably using a tool like `?dput`

Comment: This will be hard to figure out.  But let me give a little more info in the main text...

Comment: Can you please provide the output values for all of these: `class(varss)`, `class(varsg)`, `length(varss)`, `length(varsg)`, `sum(both)`, `length(int)`, `length(difs)`, `length(diff)`

Comment: `class(varss) = "data.frame"`;`class(varsg) = "data.frame"`; `length(varss) = 1`;`length(varsg)=1`;`sum(both)= 0`; `length(int)=0`;`length(difs)=1`;`length(diff)=1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All of the functions you have shown do not play well with lists or data.frames, e.g:

```
varss <- list(a = 1:8)
varsg <- list(a = 2:9)

both <- varss %in% varsg
both
# [1] FALSE

#What is in Both
int <- intersect(varss,varsg)
int
# list()

#What is different in varss
difs <- setdiff(varss,varsg)
difs
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#What is different in varsg
difg <- setdiff(varsg,varss)
difg
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I suggest you switch to vectors by doing:

```
varss <- unlist(varss)
varsg <- unlist(varsg)
```

Comment: That's what I've already tried.  Unless there are no differences in these actual lists, I only get a `1` when using `length`.  just using `intersect(varss,varsg)` will generate a long list... which hardly equals `1`... so curious whether there is something fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: Thanks!  "unlisting" it worked.  I now can identify the SNPs that aren't equal.  My analysis was telling me that 13 don't match and now doing above has identified those 13.